# JavaScript Search string error

Tags: javascript, string, search, caret

My problem is with the javascript search string function. I'm not able to find the symbol "^" in my string. 
For example:

```
string = "2^3";
n = string.search("^");
console.log(n);
```

With this example it would log i = "0". 
But the "^" is in "1".
This works with any other search than caret ('^').

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

> The `search()` method executes a search for a match between a **regular
>   expression** and this `String` object.

```
str.search(regexp)
```

So it expects a regex. `^` is a regex special character. You need to escape it:

```
n = string.search("\\^");
```

Or simply use a regex:

```
n = string.search(/\^/);
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [`String.prototype.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#Parameters) docs, the first parameter passed will be treated as a Regular Expression.

> regexp
>
> A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is
>   passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new
>   RegExp(obj).

So, the string you are passing, is converted to a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object and `^` in Regular expression, means that the first character. So, it returns the index of the first character, `0`.

You actually have to escape `^` like this `\\^`

```
var inputString = "2^3";
var n = inputString.search("\\^");
console.log(n);
```

**Output**

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

it wants a regex. strings without special characters in them look the same as a regex, but that isn't the case when there are special characters.

```
<script>

string = "2^3";
n = string.search(/\^/);
console.log(n); //1

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why your code doesn't work has already been explained by other answers. Yet the simplest solution is missing: Use [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead of `.search`:

```
var n = inputString.indexOf("^");
```